# Mypy can't find python-dateutil even after importing types-python-dateutil

Tags: python, mypy, python-dateutil, pre-commit.com

I am running `Mypy v0.910` with `pre-commit`.  It complains that `python-dateutil` does not have type stubs.  However, even after installing the stubs, I get the same error.

My pre-commit config is

```
default_language_version:
  python: python3
repos:
  <other hooks>
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.910
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args:
            - --install-types
        additional_dependencies: [tokenize-rt==3.2.0]
```

When I try to commit, it complains that the stubs are not there and then fails to install them.

```
mypy.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: mypy
- exit code: 1

coordinator/policy.py:5: error: Library stubs not installed for "dateutil.parser" (or incompatible with Python 3.7)
coordinator/policy.py:5: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-python-dateutil"
coordinator/policy.py:5: note: (or run "mypy --install-types" to install all missing stub packages)
tests/test_policy.py:6: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "pyhocon"
coordinator/configuration.py:4: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "pyhocon"
coordinator/configuration.py:4: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 3 errors in 3 files (checked 7 source files)

Installing missing stub packages:
/Users/me/.cache/pre-commit/repov_smpwjv/py_env-python3/bin/python -m pip install types-python-dateutil

Install? [yN] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.cache/pre-commit/repov_smpwjv/py_env-python3/bin/mypy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_entry())
  File "/Users/me/.cache/pre-commit/repov_smpwjv/py_env-python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypy/__main__.py", line 11, in console_entry
    main(None, sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
  File "mypy/main.py", line 120, in main
  File "mypy/main.py", line 1161, in install_types
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

There appears to be an open issue related to this on python-dateutil: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/383

Is there a way to tell `Mypy` not to worry about the missing stubs?  At the moment, the only workaround that I can think of is to completely disable `Mypy`.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Sort of.  I reverted to `rev: v0.800`

Answer (score 4):

This issue still exits on the latest mypy hook 0.971

This is the hook that causes the problem

```
  - hooks:
      - description: Type checking for Python
        exclude: tests/.*$
        id: mypy
    repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.971
```

The only way I have been able to solve it is by modifying the hook above as

```
  - hooks:
      - additional_dependencies: [types-python-dateutil==2.8.19]
        description: Type checking for Python
        exclude: tests/.*$
        id: mypy
    repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.971
```

When run locally as poetry run mypy src, you still need to add types-python-dateutil as a dev dependency

Answer (score 0):

It seems as per the below link that from version 0.931 of mypy this does not happen:
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11920

Comment: Currently I'm on `rev: v1.0.1` and still facing the same issue. So it seems to not be solved.